# How to load an array in labels?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an array that retrieves data from a csv file.

```
 String[] array = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\\arrayexample.csv").Split(';');
```

This array is now filled till array[10]. What is the best way to load data in the array to labels? For example, can I load all the data in generated labels:

```
label1  // array[0]
label2  // array[1]
label3  // array[2]
..and so on.
```

I can do it manually by adding the labels myself but is there a way to program it? Also, will this work using System.IO?

```
label1.AppendText(array[i]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of application you are targetting ? winform wpf asp.net ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that there is a one-to-one correspondence between your labels and the strings in the `array`, you can put these labels in an array, and then set the data in them using a loop, like this:

```
var labels = new[] {label1, label2, label3, ...};
for (var i = 0 ; i != array.Length ; i++) {
    labels[i].Text = array[i];
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but it shows an error: 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' doest not contain a definition for 'AppendText' and no extension method 'AppendText' accepting a first argument could be found'.

Comment: @DavidAsssad See if the changed version works for you. Note that you need to make sure that the number of labels is greater than or equal to the number of strings in the file, otherwise this is going to crash.

Comment: Thanks. The changed version is working. Just out of curiosity, why did AppendText not work? Is it because we can only set a text value for a label?

Comment: @DavidAsssad This is because `Label` does not provide an `AppendText` method: `TextBox` has it, but `Label` does not.

Comment: `AppendText` is defined for a `TextBox` (among others), but not a `Label` control. You could write your own extension method to use it.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(String labelText in array)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text(labelText);
    // Do whatever you want with each label here. i.e. add to your form.
}
```